# Can I perform the 5 daily prayers in English?

Tags: salat, english

I am new to Islam but since I began my journey turning to and submitting myself to Allah two months ago I've been having trouble with starting to pray. I was raised Catholic then became an Atheist for some time. I started reading books on Islam and the Quran recently and found myself becoming more and more attracted to Islam. I have accepted Allah and thank and praise him with all my heart for saving my life and have accepted the prophet Muhammad (Peace be upon him) as Allah's final prophet. I want to start a connection with Allah with prayer to express my love and thanks to him but it's a little difficult for me to pray the 5 prayers in Arabic although I am practicing Arabic phrases and prayers when I can. My question is:

Can I pray the 5 daily prayers in English until I memorize and learn how to pray in Arabic?